How to invoke scrollTo such that to happen after the reflow of a list (ul) with images?
I created a React application using an  (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/) element containing images with various dimensions and max-width: 25%. At the page's load, I invoke scrollTo({top: some-list-top-value}) on the list to scroll it to a particular position. I also capture the list's scroll changes and observe that immediately after moving to some-list-top-value, the list scrolls down a bit more. If I don't place the images, the list scrolls to some-list-top-value without further unwanted scroll. How should I fix this?

useEffect(() => {
    // scrollTo(top) = listRef.current?.scrollTo({ top })
    setTimeout(scrollTo, 0, cachedScrollTop);
    // directly using scrollTo exhibits the after-scroll scrolling behaviour
    // scrollTo(cachedScrollTop); // -> after-scroll scrolling
}, []);

Surprisingly, using setTimeout solved my issue.
